# Stop word using HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

In this condition I want to read data from a file, but not all the words. Is this condition correct? `set` in the following code is a `HashSet`.

```
if (!set.contains(word.toString().equals(set)))
{ 
    word.set(str);
    context.write(word, one);
}
else 
    continue;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense but we can't fix it because you haven't explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: @shmosel i want to read data from text file but i dont want to read all the word some just some of word and i stored stop word in hashset

Comment: Nothing related to bigdata or Hadoop here.

Answer (score 0):

This code would not work, because the `contains` method on `Set` checks by means of `equals`, whether the Set contains the item.  You do not need to use the equals check again.

```
if (!set.contains(word))
{ 
    word.add(word);
}
else 
    continue;
```

I am not sure I get what you asked, but hope this helps. Leave a comment and I would be glad to edit/remove my answer.